# Importing xlsx file - wrong output

Tags: r

I was trying to do a lot of things and I searched a lot of websites but I have problem with a simple code. I have a lot of formulas in my excel file.

```
library(readxl)
GCOC <- read_excel("GCOC.xlsx", header = TRUE)
GCOC

Error in read_excel("GCOC.xlsx", header = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (header = TRUE)
> GCOC
                                   V1
1                      PK\003\004\024
2 ¾\020½¼+2ð:\030ëg…ø\031¿wžE†¤¼Q.x(Ä
>
```

Comment: Do you mean `col_names = TRUE`? Doesn't look like there is a `header` argument for `read_excel`. Also, is your problem that you have the error for the unused argument, or does the file not look like you would expect? Please provide more info :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I need to use the answer.
Maybe you can try the "read.xlsx" function from the "openxlsx" package.